# Bibliography citations

Tags: bibliographies

My citation for bibliography appear unsorted in the text like [6,3,4] instead of [3,4,6]. How can I make the appear sorted. I don't care how they appear at the end where they are all listed but my worry is for the appearance in the text. I have tried unsrt style but it does not make any difference. I am using \bibliographystyle{ieeetr}.
Tash

Comment: Please post a Minimal (non-)Working Example of code which people can compile to reproduce your issue and test solutions. This greatly increases the chances of your receiving effective, timely responses by helping people to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're using a numeric citation style and haven't indicated that you're using a citation management package such as `natbib`, you could get the citation numbers sorted by loading the `cite` package:

```
\usepackage{cite}
```

Comment: Thank Mico, this worked perfectly. I also used notoccite package to fix the order. Great.

Answer (score 1):

If you use biblatex,  you can choose a numeric style, for instance, and obtain what you want with this line in your preamble:

```
\usepackage[style=numeric,sortcites=true]{biblatex}
```

The `sortcites=true` option makes the citations be sorted as in the bibliography.

Comment: Since the OP has indicated that he/she is using the `ieeetr` bibliography style, it's not very likely that he/she is using `biblatex`.

Comment: @Mico: Well, I thought maybe the OP used or might consider using biblatex-ieee.